# Simple key/value retrieval using Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I'm using Firebase as a simple key/value datastore:

```
4885301901104318378: {
    title: "document title"
}
```

Trying to retrieve a value based on the key returns a bizarrely sliced up object.

```
db.orderByKey().equalTo(id).once('value', function(data) {
  console.log(data) //{S {A: T, W: U, g: Yd}}
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, but I must say that Firebase makes this much harder than it needs to be.  At the very least, this example should be front-and-center in the documentation.

Comment: Where did you not see it in the documentation? It should be on every page including the main sample on the home page. I just want to make sure it's displayed everywhere correctly. Also, a snapshot is better than just the data because provides helper methods for iteration, child count, and the snapshot value is immutable.

Comment: I agree with @Indolering, this interface is very confusing. It resembles an event type framework when I want to do a singular data access. Doesn't match with having a `set()` function, there should be a simple matching `get()` function to retrieve a node's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event listener returns a [`DataSnapshot`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/) object.

Call the `.val()` function on the snapshot to retrieve the data.

```
db.orderByKey().equalTo(id).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val()) 
});
```

Read the [Retrieving Data docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-start) for all the details on syncing data from Firebase.

The strange looking object `{S {A: T, W: U, g: Yd}}` is just minified code that helps keep shrink the download size of `firebase.js`.